# How to extracting NSMutableArray data to String Array

Tags: nsmutablearray, swift2

Sorry I'm very new to Swift, and detailed explanation would be appreciated.

In my program, I have a NSMutableArray variable called `dict`, where the data has been converted from JSON file. I need to extract the data out into a String variable or Object that is able to store all the values.

[image: String values residing in <code>dict</code>]

An example of the output I require:

```
stringObject[0] = ("MATISSE", "JASON SHAPIRO", "9:00AM", "EXPLORE THE TOPICS AND TOOLS RELATED TO TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT.", "TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT")

stringObject[1] = ("ROTHKO", "JIM WHITE", "9:00AM", "DISCUSS THE LATEST SET OF TOOLS USED TO HELP EASE SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT.", "JAVA TOOLS")
```

It is important that the positioning of the variable is fixed, so that when I do a for loop, I will extract that same position of all objects.

Comment: You shouldn't name "dict" something that is actually an NSArray, it will harm you at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [allValues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDictionary/allValues) method of the dictionary.

You would do

```
[dict[0] allValues]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I require is an array of string objects. So like `stringObject` is an array of objects, that stores an array of string. Sorry your solution maybe correct, but I am very new to Swift. Can you provide detailed solution?

Comment: Please answer in Swift to questions tagged "swift". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can get this by:

```
Array(dic[0].values)
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I require is an array of string objects. So like `stringObject` is an array of objects, that stores an array of string. Sorry your solution maybe correct, but I am very new to Swift. Can you provide detailed solution?

Comment: @JoeLeong It's unclear what you're asking. Anya's answer is ok (well, almost: replace ".values" which is for Swift Dictionary with ".allValues" which is for NSDictionary) and will give you a list of each dictionary's values, as in your example.

Comment: @joe as I saw keys and values all are of string type so  dic[0].values = will return collection  of all values from dic and Array(dic[0].values) will convert that into array.